# Returning a collection of rectangles from another class using built in functions

Tags: python, object, repr

My question is, using class Square which creates how ever many squares the user wants, how would I return a list of all the squares by overriding **repr** method in another class called SquareList?

The following code will initialize a single rectangle:

```
>>>b5 = Square(Test(),Test(2,3),"green")
>>>b5
>>>Square(Test(),Test(2,3),"green")
```

Don't worry about Test(), it is another class that just initializes all of the x and y values for class Square.

Now for class SquareList:

What I want to do is be able to create multiple squares just like above by creating a function in SquareList and calling it by `a.add_more_squares(b5)` where b5 is the rectangle and `a = SquareList()`

By typing in `a` in IDLE, it should return a list of all the squares that i've added to the SquareList. Would I have to mess around with the **repr** method in SquareList class?

Comment: Why do you need your own class to store a list of objects?

Answer (score 0):

If you need a string representation of an object, you need to mess with `__repr__` yes.

However, you could just delegate to the existing `list.__repr__` if you're storing a `list` type

Comment: Is it possible to call a repr from another class inside of that class's repr? The repr for SquareList class should be a list of each repr in square class

Comment: Yes `return repr(list_of_things)`